# query runs one time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron

I have created a PHP file using while loop and when I run my PHP file using cron job, it runs just once!

> /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://alhyipmonitors.com/sites.php
>   1>/dev/null 2>&1

I have 22 monitor id's in my monitor's database table which I am selecting from.

Here is my code:

```
$q='select * from `monitors`';
            $result=@mysql_query($q);
            while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            $mid =  $row['mid'];

    $q='select * from `monitors` where `mid`="'.$mid.'"';
    $result=mysql_query($q);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo'<h2>'.$row['monitor_url'].'</h2>';

        if($row['robot_target'])
        {
            $url=$row['robot_target'];
            $ch=curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            $handle=fopen('src.txt','w');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $handle);
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            fclose($handle);
            $handle=fopen('src.txt','r');
            $html_code=fread($handle, filesize('src.txt'));
            fclose($handle);

            if($html_code!='')
            {
                if(preg_match_all($row['robot_pattern'], $html_code, $match))
                {
                    $i=0;
                    $j=0;
                    while($j<=50 && $match[$row['robot_id_index']][$i] && $match[$row['robot_key_index']][$i])
                    {
                        $id=$match[$row['robot_id_index']][$i];
                        $key1=$match[$row['robot_key_index']][$i];
                        $key2=remove_extra_in_url($key1);
                        $key3=remove_extra_in_string($key1);
                        $key4=str_replace(' ','-',$key1);
                        $button=$row['button_pattern'].$id.$row['end_button_pattern'];

                        $details=$row['details_pattern'].$id.$row['end_details_pattern'];
                        echo $i.'. ID= <b>'.$id.'</b>, KEY1= <b>'.$key1.'</b>, KEY2= <b>'.$key2.'</b>, KEY3= <b>'.$key3.'</b>, KEY4= <b>'.$key4.'</b>, <a href="'.$button.'" target="_blank">BUTTON</a>, <a href="'.$details.'" target="_blank">DETAILS</a><br/>';
                        $q='select * from `buttons` where `button_url`="'.$button.'"';

                        if($num=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($q))==0)
                        { 
                            $q='select * from `programs` where `url` like "%'.$key1.'%" or `url` like "%'.$key2.'%" or `url` like "%'.$key3.'%" or `url` like "%'.$key4.'%" or `url`="'.$key2.'" order by `pid` desc';
                            $result=mysql_query($q);
                            $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
                            if($num==1)
                            {
                                $program=mysql_fetch_array($result);
                                $piid = $program['pid'];
                                $urll = $program['url'];

                                // Attempt update query execution

$data='update `programs` set `monitors`=`monitors`+1 where pid="'.$program['pid'].'" and url="'.$program['url'].'"';

$val=mysql_query($data);
if($val == 1){

    $q='insert into `buttons` values("","'.$program['pid'].'","'.$row['mid'].'","'.$details.'","'.$button.'")';
                                if(mysql_query($q))
                                    echo'<div class="green">'.$program['url'].' -> Added.</div>';
                                $j++;                           
}                           

                            }
                            elseif($num>1)
                            {
                                while($program=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                {
                                    echo'<div class="blue">'.$program['url'].' [ <a href="fr.php?a=add_button&mid='.$row['mid'].'&pid='.$program['pid'].'&bid='.$id.'" target="_blank">ADD FOR THIS PROGRAM</a> ]</div>';
                                }
                                $j++;
                            }
                            else
                                echo'<b style="color: red;">Not Found</b><br/>';
                    }
                        else
                            echo'<b style="color: green;">Button URL is already exist</b><br/>';
                        echo'<br/><hr/>';   
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
                else
                    echo'Preg Match -> Not Found';
            }
            else
                echo'file get contents -> error';
        }
        else
            echo'robot target -> not fount';
    }
```

Every help is welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you kindly indent your code properly. It really helps to make the code more readable.

Comment: _Don't_ use the *deprecated and insecure* `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: my dear Magnus Eriksson
Can you give me complete code using your point which you saying

Comment: We're not here to do your job for you. Use the PHP manual and search for tutorials regarding mysqli or pdo.

Comment: Why are you first getting _all_ rows from `monitors` and while iterating through the results, you fetch each row _again_? You already have the result for that row in the variable `$row` at that point.

Comment: i have try both but its showing same i mean just get result 1st monitors id.
i have total 22 monitors in my table

Comment: i have add my code in this page.http://alhyipmonitors.com/fr.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you are reusing the variable $result inside your loop.

```
$q = 'select * from `monitors`';
$result = @mysql_query($q);
while( $row = @mysql_fetch_array($result) ) // <-- $result var
{
    $mid =  $row['mid'];

    $q = 'select * from `monitors` where `mid`="'.$mid.'"';

    // $result = mysql_query($q); // <--- overwrite $result var
    $result1 = mysql_query($q);  // <--- use a different var name
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result1); // <--- change here too
    echo'<h2>'.$row['monitor_url'].'</h2>';
    // more code etc
}
```

Comment: Please can you give me complete code
Because i have try this one 
' $q='select * from `monitors`';
   $result=@mysql_query($q);
   while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {
   
 echo'<h2>'.$row['monitor_url'].'</h2>';  '

But its also run one time

Comment: i have try your code but it still run one time  i mean just getting 1st one $mid

Comment: Edit your question and add your table definition, and provide some sample data that goes into that table. Explain what you want to accomplish. Indent your code.

Comment: @AyanAbraiz That's because you're reusing `$result` and `$row` several times in your code. (probably more variables as well). Quickest fix, don't reuse variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Because you reset `$result` in `while` loop,to resolve it rename inner `$result` to another one, I have specified edited lines by comments

```
<?php

$q='select * from `monitors`';
            $result=@mysql_query($q);
            while($row=@mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            $mid =  $row['mid'];

    $q='select * from `monitors` where `mid`="'.$mid.'"';
    $result=mysql_query($q);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo'<h2>'.$row['monitor_url'].'</h2>';

        if($row['robot_target'])
        {
            $url=$row['robot_target'];
            $ch=curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            $handle=fopen('src.txt','w');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $handle);
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            fclose($handle);
            $handle=fopen('src.txt','r');
            $html_code=fread($handle, filesize('src.txt'));
            fclose($handle);

            if($html_code!='')
            {
                if(preg_match_all($row['robot_pattern'], $html_code, $match))
                {
                    $i=0;
                    $j=0;
                    while($j<=50 && $match[$row['robot_id_index']][$i] && $match[$row['robot_key_index']][$i])
                    {
                        $id=$match[$row['robot_id_index']][$i];
                        $key1=$match[$row['robot_key_index']][$i];
                        $key2=remove_extra_in_url($key1);
                        $key3=remove_extra_in_string($key1);
                        $key4=str_replace(' ','-',$key1);
                        $button=$row['button_pattern'].$id.$row['end_button_pattern'];

                        $details=$row['details_pattern'].$id.$row['end_details_pattern'];
                        echo $i.'. ID= <b>'.$id.'</b>, KEY1= <b>'.$key1.'</b>, KEY2= <b>'.$key2.'</b>, KEY3= <b>'.$key3.'</b>, KEY4= <b>'.$key4.'</b>, <a href="'.$button.'" target="_blank">BUTTON</a>, <a href="'.$details.'" target="_blank">DETAILS</a><br/>';
                        $q='select * from `buttons` where `button_url`="'.$button.'"';

                        if($num=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($q))==0)
                        { 
                            $q='select * from `programs` where `url` like "%'.$key1.'%" or `url` like "%'.$key2.'%" or `url` like "%'.$key3.'%" or `url` like "%'.$key4.'%" or `url`="'.$key2.'" order by `pid` desc';
                            $innser_result=mysql_query($q); // Here change $result to $inner_result or what you want
                            $num=mysql_num_rows($innser_result); // Here change $result to $inner_result or what you want
                            if($num==1)
                            {
                                $program=mysql_fetch_array($innser_result); // Here change $result to $inner_result or what you want
                                $piid = $program['pid'];
                                $urll = $program['url'];

                                // Attempt update query execution

$data='update `programs` set `monitors`=`monitors`+1 where pid="'.$program['pid'].'" and url="'.$program['url'].'"';

$val=mysql_query($data);
if($val == 1){

    $q='insert into `buttons` values("","'.$program['pid'].'","'.$row['mid'].'","'.$details.'","'.$button.'")';
                                if(mysql_query($q))
                                    echo'<div class="green">'.$program['url'].' -> Added.</div>';
                                $j++;                           
}                           

                            }
                            elseif($num>1)
                            {
                                while($program=mysql_fetch_array($innser_result)) // Here change $result to $inner_result or what you want
                                {
                                    echo'<div class="blue">'.$program['url'].' [ <a href="fr.php?a=add_button&mid='.$row['mid'].'&pid='.$program['pid'].'&bid='.$id.'" target="_blank">ADD FOR THIS PROGRAM</a> ]</div>';
                                }
                                $j++;
                            }
                            else
                                echo'<b style="color: red;">Not Found</b><br/>';
                    }
                        else
                            echo'<b style="color: green;">Button URL is already exist</b><br/>';
                        echo'<br/><hr/>';   
                        $i++;
                    }
                }
                else
                    echo'Preg Match -> Not Found';
            }
            else
                echo'file get contents -> error';
        }
        else
            echo'robot target -> not fount';
    }
```

Comment: i have try to use your code but it still run one time i mean get just 1st $mid = 1
you can check here : http://alhyipmonitors.com/fr.php